# Troubles with libpng12.so.0 - no version information available?

Tags: 20.04, libpng

I downloaded [GMAT](https://gmat.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/GW/overview) and ran it according to the instructions:

```
$ ./GMAT-R2018a 
./GMAT-R2018a: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I thought libpng was missing. So I downloaded, built and installed libpng 1.6.37 from source.

```
$ ./GMAT-R2018a 
./GMAT-R2018a: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So apparently I needed specifically version 1.2 of libpng, which I downloaded, built and installed from source:

```
$ ./GMAT-R2018a 
./GMAT-R2018a: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So apparently somehow GMAT couldn't see the file, so I made a symlink:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpng12.so.0 libpng12.so.0
$ ./GMAT-R2018a 
./GMAT-R2018a: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I found a post somewhere saying that I should add a repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

So *now* when I run GMAT, I get a new error:

```
$ ./GMAT-R2018a 
./GMAT-R2018a: /usr/local/lib/libpng12.so.0: no version information available (required by /home/steen/GMAT/GMAT/R2018a/bin/../lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0)
```

And now I'm all out of ideas. Anyone?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm running a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is the libpng12, which is removed from the repositories after 16.04 LTS.
To install it use [special PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

Then download and extract GMAT:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://deac-riga.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gmat/GMAT/GMAT-R2018a/gmat-ubuntu-x64-R2018a.tar.gz
tar -xf gmat-ubuntu-x64-R2018a.tar.gz
cd GMAT/R2018a
./GMAT-R2018a
```

---

So you have to remove problematic library with:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libpng12.so.0
```

Comment: E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work in 22.04

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libpng12-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate
```